# Gthumb 3 for ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, gthumb

I have ubuntu 10.04 installed and I don't want to upgrade, but I do want to enjoy new features of gthumb 3, like ability to import from folders etc.
After some googling, I found that 2.13.1 is the last gthumb version for lucid due to dependencies to GTK+ 2.24. Is there any way to make it working without upgrade? Patches? Hacks? Even version 2.13.90 is enough...

Thanks in advance,
Alexander Noshe

Answer (score 1):

No, it's unlikely to be backported for Lucid. Lucid is reaching the end of it's life next month, I highly encourage you to update at least to precise 12.04, which is quite nice.

Comment: Tried that 2-3 months ago, it replaced my gnome to unity, all my settings were deleted, in short, it became unusable... I like my lucid settings and don't want to change anything.

Comment: You can install stock GNOME back into Ubuntu, replacing Unity. Seriously, if you keep using Lucid beyond the end of next month, you'll stop receiving security updates, and that's a really dangerous situation to be in for a computer that connects to the internet. You have been warned.